# Lambda to lambda call set timeout from calling function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

My use case is something like this. I have two lambdas: lambda_1 and lambda_2.
I am calling lambda_2 inside lambda_1 using aws.Lambda.invoke(). The timeout defined for lambda_2 in configurations is 3 seconds.

Now, my question is, is there any way to change the timeout for lambda_2 while calling the invoke function on it?

Is there any service/script/config parameters to achieve this?

Comment: No, it's not possible. I wonder what would be your use case though? Why not simply increase the timeout on `lambda_2`?

Comment: Actually, in my case, only when lambda_2 is called from lambda_1 (because of the payload sent), it goes beyond specified timeout for lambda_2. For all other cases, I want the default timeout. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Not sure if this is viable at all but all I could think of is changing the timeout before and after the invoke using the SDK's updateFunctionConfiguration method.